# calling a method from a class that implements an interface (java)

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, interface, extends

My code is supposed to call the handleInput(String) method from a non-specific class that implements the interface InputType; this is to force all handler classes that could be here to have the method handleInput(String), along with some other methods.

Am I doing this wrong? Eclipse says that

```
The method handleInput(String) is undefined for the type
Class<capture#5-of ? extends InputType>
```

Code:

```
public void registerNewInput(String name, Class<? extends InputType> typeHandler)
{
    inputHandlers.put(name, typeHandler);
}

public void handleInput(String handlerName, String input)
{
    Class<? extends InputType> handler = (Class<? extends InputType>) inputHandlers.get(handlerName);
    handler.handleInput(input);
}
```

Comment: `handler` is instance of `java.lang.Class` not `InputType`. By the way provide source code of `InputType`

Comment: You're casting to the `Class` _object_ not to an instance of your class. Cast to `InputType` not to `Class<? extends InputType>`.

Comment: @Amir Pashazadeh
would that use the Class instanceof InputType, if that was what i was going for?  I am trying to make it take in a class that has predefined methods.  I believe that to do that it has to implement an interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need generics to accomplish this.  Simply use the interface name as your type:

```
public void registerNewInput(String name, InputType typeHandler)
{
    inputHandlers.put(name, typeHandler);
}

public void handleInput(String handlerName, String input)
{
    InputType handler = (InputType) inputHandlers.get(handlerName);
    handler.handleInput(input);
}
```

The reason you don't need generics here is because Java types can always be assigned to a variable of a more general type.  I.e. - if `Circle` extends `Shape`, then a `Circle` can be assigned to a reference of type `Shape`:

```
Shape s = new Circle();  // works just fine
```

So in this example, it allows you to declare your parameter as type `InputType` and pass anything that implements `InputType` when calling the method.

Additionally, you can save yourself a cast by parameterizing your map

```
private Map<String, InputType> inputHandlers;

public void registerNewInput(String name, InputType typeHandler)
{
    inputHandlers.put(name, typeHandler);
}

public void handleInput(String handlerName, String input)
{
    InputType handler = inputHandlers.get(handlerName); // no cast needed here
    handler.handleInput(input);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately i giotta go for a bit, but ill test later and get back here on how it went.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with the *class* and not an *instance* of your `InputType`. You have to create an instance of that class and then call `handleInput` on it:

```
public void handleInput(String handlerName, String input)
{
    Class<? extends InputType> clazz = inputHandlers.get(handlerName);
    InputType handler = clazz.newInstance();
    handler.handleInput(input);
}
```

But this seems rather convoluted. Is there a reason that you're storing the class of the handler instead of an instance of the handler itself? You could easily do this instead:

```
public void registerNewInput(String name, InputType inputType) {
    inputHandlers.put(name, inputType); //This assumes your map is of type Map<String, InputType>
}

public void handleInput(String handlerName, String input) {
    InputType inputType = InputType inputHandlers.get(handlerName);
    inputType.handleInput(input);
}
```

Comment: @ajb Actually my earlier answer was completely wrong; he needs to create an instance of the handler *from* the class and not work directly with the class.

Comment: I don't see how we can tell, since we don't know what `inputHandlers` is or how it's declared.  I think we're all just guessing about what the OP really wants.

Comment: I think we can be sure that `inputHandlers` would have to be of type `Map<String, Class<? extends InputType>>` otherwise he would be seeing compilation errors for `registerNewInput`.

Answer (score 0):

If `handler` is supposed to be of some class that implements `InputType`, then just declare it like this:

```
InputType handler = inputHandlers.get(handlerName);
```

Whenever you declare a variable like this:

```
SomeClass x;
```

it means that, at runtime, `x` can be a `SomeClass` **or any subclass of SomeClass**.  For an interface, `x` can be of any class that implements the interface.  I'm guessing that that's what you were trying to say with `Class<? extends InputType>`.

**EDIT:** If I've guessed correctly what you're trying to do, then changing `Class<? extends InputType>` to simply `InputType` should be done everywhere, including the `typeHandler` parameter of `registerNewInput`, and in your `Map` type if you're using one.  A `Class` object is a special type of object that can be used to give you information *about* a class; don't use the type for declaring objects that should just be in some unknown class.  (On the other hand, if you are really sure you *do* want a `Class` object, please clarify what you're trying to accomplish.)

Comment: This won't compile. The type of the value of the map is `Class<? extends InputType>` which isn't the same as `InputType`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath I'm speculating that `Class<? extends InputType>` does not belong _anywhere_ in the code, and that the OP was confused about how to declare things that must implement `InputType`.  But as I said in another comment, we're pretty much just guessing.  I'll edit my answer to clarify this.